# How to store images in SQLite and also how I can export input text and image in any tabular format?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-sqlite

1) Please help me out to store image submitted by button to SQLite.

2) How can I implement export function in my app so that all the input text and images stored in SQLite can be exported in any format but in tabular way so that exported file can be used to retrieve data again.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.himanshu.instrumentalinformationcollector;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "instruments.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "instrument_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "LOCATION";
public static final String COL_4 = "INFORMATION";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            DatabaseHelper.COL_1 + " INTEGER,"
            + DatabaseHelper.COL_2  + " TEXT,"
            + DatabaseHelper.COL_3 + " TEXT,"
            + DatabaseHelper.COL_4 + " TEXT);";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

}
public boolean insertData(Integer ID, String name, String location, String information){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_1,ID);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_2,name);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_3,location);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_4,information);

    sqLiteDatabase.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    return true;
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.himanshu.instrumentalinformationcollector;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
DatabaseHelper myDB;
EditText editMessage,editMessage1,editMessage2,editMessage3;
Button submitData;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    editMessage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editMessage1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editMessage2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editMessage3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    submitData=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    AddData();

}

public void AddData(){
    submitData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    boolean isInserted = myDB.insertData(Integer.valueOf(editMessage.getText().toString()),editMessage1.getText().toString(),editMessage2.getText().toString(),editMessage3.getText().toString());
                if(isInserted == true)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

        Bitmap bmp = null;

        try {
            bmp = getBitmapFromUri(selectedImage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }


}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
            getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.himanshu.instrumentalinformationcollector.MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ID"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:background="@drawable/gray"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/img"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Upload"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30sp"
            android:hint="Please enter here"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:inputType="number"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/editText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
            android:hint="Full Name"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Location"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Please enter here"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Information"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Describe briefly"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        >
    </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/export"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Export"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is lengthy - and will require you to make many changes.

**Saving Images:**

- If you want to save the images, you will need to convert the image to a byte array
- A more feasible approach, is to save the image as a File within your app's internal storage, add a column to your database which saves the name of the image in a common directory "s8u903wmips.jpg" as an example.

**Exporting Data:**

- Content Providers are created for exactly this reason. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html
- Content providers are one of the primary building blocks of Android applications, providing content to applications. They encapsulate data and provide it to applications through the single ContentResolver interface. A content provider is only required if you need to share data between multiple applications. For example, the contacts data is used by multiple applications and must be stored in a content provider. If you don't need to share data amongst multiple applications you can use a database directly via SQLiteDatabase.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information. 

I only want that the data is stored in SQLite database and when required transferred to server manually in exported format.

Comment: +1 for storing the file path and not the raw image bytes. The "export" function in the OP sounds more like a tool for the user to backup/transfer his own data, in which case a ContentProvider is unnecessary.

Comment: @Himanshu there is no built in "export" function, you would have to write it yourself. That means you can export to any format you like using standard java file writing (search the web for examples). You can also write code to read those files and "import" data into your database that way.